# Do the Spanish domestic Trenhotel lines still operate?

Tags: trains, spain, night-transport

The international Trenhotel services from Paris to Madrid and Barcelona were sadly withdrawn in December 2013.  Renfe still describes the [domestic trenhotel](http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/larga_distancia/productos/trenhotel.html) services such as Barcelona - Granada, as does [EUrail](http://www.eurail.com/europe-by-train/night-trains/trenhotel-domestic-night-train) but I can't find this train in the [Renfe online timetable](http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/index.html) and [rail.cc claims it is withdrawn](https://en.rail.cc/granada-valencia-barcelona/trenhotel-894-alhambra/night-trains-city/11260/83), which would make it somewhat odd that Renfe still advertises for it.  Does this night train still exist?

Comment: @pnuts Good find.  Regrettably, it still doesn't show up when searching for a later date.  However, considering my experiences with the completeness of the RENFE booking system, that does not mean it won't run again; perhaps they aren't bookable until RENFE is sure when track works are finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes domestic tren hotel services are still running.

http://www.renfe.com/EN/viajeros/larga_distancia/productos/trenhotel.html

Also renfe have recent started investing in new carriages for these services,

http://www.renfe.com/EN/viajeros/nuestros_trenes/trenhotel.html

Just to make sure my info was correct I did a time table search on one of the routes and came up with this

[image]

Comment: How about Barcelona - Granada?

Comment: They are still advertising it. http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/larga_distancia/productos/trenhotel.html  However the line work is still going on and a timetable search is still shoving changes onto buses well into November.  I suspect that the Alhambra service may not resume until the following year