# Is the Trenhotel eliminated starting from Dec 12th?

Tags: trains, europe, bookings

I tried to book the overnight Trenhotel from Hendaye to Lisbon at the Renfe website and, while all days before an on Dec 11th can be booked normally (expect Dec 5th, which is sold out) all other dates) show "Sorry, it is not possible to book at this moment". It does not show sold out as it does for Dec 5th. Is this train eliminated for good?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the Spanish domestic Trenhotel lines still operate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52318/do-the-spanish-domestic-trenhotel-lines-still-operate)

Comment: @gerrit Not really. I'm asking about the 2017 winter season and it is about the Hendaye to Lisbon section, not the domestic ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Man in Seat 61 trains go on sale in Spain 60 days before departure. However [here](https://www.seat61.com/Spain-trains.htm#How_to_buy_train_tickets_for_Spain) he says:

> The opening of reservations can be delayed for dates after the twice-yearly timetable change in June and December, as they're always late loading the data.
>   The 60/90 days isn't exact, indeed, I often find that Renfe loads trains as and when it feels like it, often less than 60 days and sometimes certain trains appear on the system before others.  If you don't see the complete train service which you are expecting to see, and it's over a month to go before departure, the chances are that not all trains have been loaded yet.

So best to be patient. His Portugal pages confirm the information.

Comment: Thank you a lot for information! I was getting sad that I would not be able to take the train to go to Lisbon from France this Christmas.

Comment: For this year (2017): on Sunday 10 December there is the winter change of timetable.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi How do you know that? The timetable still is the same in 9 and 10 December and still not available after the 12.

Comment: @GabrielDiego: it is the standardized main date for timetables changes across Europe, for international travel, but usually all public transportation use it: after looking for references, it comes to Annex VII to Directive 2012/34/EU e.g. in http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32012L0034

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Ok thanks. However, it seems that Renfe may be a bit off this date by a couple days and they still have not updated their booking system with the new timetable.

Comment: @GabrielDiego: for long travel train, the things are slightly different: the departing date is important (and if the train wagons are from country X, also the return journey is still planed. That Sunday the timetable is usually mixed. In any case the directive is just for internal timetable between rail companies. Rail companies take more time preparing the official published plan (usually checking wagon logistics, prices, etc). In any case, you cannot book, but also other people, so I assume you will find places.